# Handwriting detection with keras : using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I've tried to run a code example (hosted on keras.io) regarding the handwriting recognition task. While playing with the code, I faced a TensorFlow-related issue. Please see the relevant code snippet below.

```
def preprocess_image(image_path, img_size=(image_width, image_height)):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image, 1)
    image = distortion_free_resize(image, img_size)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return image


def vectorize_label(label):
    label = char_to_num(tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8"))
    length = tf.shape(label)[0]
    pad_amount = max_len - length
    label = tf.pad(label, paddings=[[0, pad_amount]], constant_values=padding_token)
    return label


def process_images_labels(image_path, label):
    image = preprocess_image(image_path)
    label = vectorize_label(label)
    return {"image": image, "label": label}


def prepare_dataset(image_paths, labels):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, labels)).map(
        process_images_labels, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE
    )
    return dataset.batch(batch_size).cache().prefetch(AUTOTUNE)

train_ds = prepare_dataset(train_img_paths, train_labels_cleaned)
validation_ds = prepare_dataset(validation_img_paths, validation_labels_cleaned)
test_ds = prepare_dataset(test_img_paths, test_labels_cleaned)
```

1. This is the code from [Handwriting recognition](https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition/) and when I add the 3 last lines I get this error:

> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`
> is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate
> this function with @tf.function.

2. I have seen some of the solutions on stack-overflow but couldn't make it work. ( Some said I should downgrade my tensorflow to 1x but I want to use 2x.)

thank you!

Comment: Please, explain what you mean by the last 3 lines. Have you successfully run that code example (without changing anything in colab)?

Comment: yes from the beginning until the last 3 line which is:                                          train_ds = prepare_dataset(train_img_paths, train_labels_cleaned)
validation_ds = prepare_dataset(validation_img_paths, validation_labels_cleaned)
test_ds = prepare_dataset(test_img_paths, test_labels_cleaned)                                           the hole code is on the link I provided. by the way I'm doing it on pycharm not colab

Comment: If it's run ok in colab and not in local, then you should check the tf version. In colab, it's 2.8.

Comment: it works fine in Colab but I want run it locally and I want to use it for detecting text from video. the problem is clearly from the prepare_dataset function but what makes it confusing for me is that the code is correct and it should work, but it's not!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is from tensor flow and it can be solved by simply updating TensorFlow to latest version
Also It is recommended to use python 3.5 to 3.8 with TensorFlow. useful link: [TensorFlow installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)